# Erro ao remover dados na Gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Pessoal toda a vez que tento remover um dado na gridview me deparo com esse erro "A fonte de dados 'SqlDataSource2' não oferece suporte para exclusão a menos que DeleteCommand seja especificado."

esse é o meu método de excluir da gridview:

```
 protected void TabelaAlimentos_DeleteRow(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        GerenciarAlimentacaoController controller = new GerenciarAlimentacaoController();

        int index = Int32.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
        int id = Int32.Parse(TabelaAlimentos.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);

        Alimento alimento = (Alimento)controller.pesquisar(id, "Alimentos");
        controller.deletar(alimento);
        TabelaAlimentos.DeleteRow(index);
        TabelaAlimentos.DataBind();



        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/img/Alimentos/") + alimento.imagemAlimento);

        file.Delete();

        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> alert('Alimento Removido com Sucesso!'); window.location=('gerenciaralimentacao.aspx'); </script>");


    }
}
```

O código é executado normalmente sem erro, mas quando sai do método o erro é gerado.

Comment: Você já tentou chama o método Rebind(); do seu grid ?

Comment: Como utilizo esse método ?

Comment: após o  file.Delete();   seugridview.Rebind();

Comment: Não tenho acesso a esse método

Comment: Consegui resolver, o que faltava era ativar o delete no sqldatasource,. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Esse método é do próprio GriView, você deve ter acesso sim, mas que bom quer deu certo.

Comment: Você tentou implementar os métodos Row_Deleting e/ou Row_Deleted lembro?

Comment: Não tentei, mas vou tentar, Obrigado pela dica